# numpy duplicate elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, expand

maybe this is a easy question, but is there a fast way to duplicate elements in a array?
It should work like this way for 3D:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

1 1 2 2 3 3
1 1 2 2 3 3
4 4 5 5 6 6
4 4 5 5 6 6
7 7 8 8 9 9
7 7 8 8 9 9
```

I tried it with 3 nested for-loops, but this was really slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6],
                  [7, 8, 9]])
>>> np.repeat(np.repeat(a, 2, 0), 2, 1)

array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9],
       [7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]])
```

Comment: Great Solution! But I figured out that this function change the dtype from float64 to float32. Can I avoid this?

Comment: @Christian - it doesn't change the dtype for me.

Comment: sorry, my fault - I used another function which destroyed the dtype. thanks! :)